# View amount of instances in AWS CloudWatch / Properly configuring instace scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm currently developing for a high-traffic website which is using AWS for (among other things) load balancing. We're in the process of configuring the load balancers so we have enough instances running to keep the site afloat, but not too many causing us to lose money.

The way we're approaching this now is by keeping an eye on the CPU utilisation in CloudWatch and changing our configuration accordingly.

A problem we're running into though is that we can't seem to figure out how to get CloudWatch to graph the amount of running instances so we can offset this to the CPU utilisation. We can only see how many instances are currently active so we end up having to check a lot of times instead of just looking back on the statistics of the past hours / days / weeks.

Ideally I'd like to see a graph of amount of instances per Elastic Beanstalk application.

I'm fairly new to AWS and all its components so it could be I'm looking at this in an entirely wrong way, so if anyone has any other suggestions and/or resources on how to properly configure the instance scaling I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/WhatIsAutoScaling.html

Comment: I'm aware of what it is and how it works, we've already had it running for quite some time. I'm just trying to figure out how to configure it as perfectly as possible, right now we are looking at average CPU loads on peak times and scaling from there, which is working okay.

I just feel that we can do it better, and something like seeing the amount of instances (the main part of my question) in CloudWatch would help us immensely with this process.

Comment: Why do think that average CUP is not good enough? If you can share that we can think of a better metric (num of connections, memory usage...). You can also add your own custom metric.

Comment: I don't think it's not good enough, I'm only trying to figure out the 'perfect' settings for our setup. I don't believe the same numbers apply for all sites so that's why I want to figure out how to monitor the amount of active instances so we can fine tune. Right now we upscale at 45% avg usage over 5 minutes and downscale at 25%. These are probably a bit low but we experienced some downtime. Again, I don't believe these exact numbers are of any use.

Comment: I'm struggling with what would you want to do with the number of instances. If you want to add different number of instances based on the number of instances you already have, you can use PercentChangeInCapacity, and add 50% each time, for example.
Anyway, you can get the number of "healthy" instances behind the ELB of your Elastic Beanstalk environment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-metricscollected.html

Comment: So I can look at the CPU usage history in CloudWatch, and compare it to how many instances were running at that time, the healthy instances count didn't seem to be equal to how many actually were running. I think I'll be adding a custom metric for it by using http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/cli-mon-put-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out how to see the amount of running instances in CloudWatch. So I decided to measure them myself through the AWS PHP SDK which actually turned out to be much easier than I thought.

Here is the code from my cron command for anyone that wants to know:

```
public function fire(){
    $client = AWS::get('CloudWatch');

    $containers = [
       'production',
       'staging'
    ];

    foreach($containers as $container){
        $client->putMetricData([
            'Namespace'  => 'Company',
            'MetricData' => [
                [
                    'MetricName' => 'NumberOfInstances',
                    'Timestamp'  => time(),
                    'Value'      => $this->_getInstanceCount($container),
                    'Dimensions' => [
                        [
                            'Name'  => 'Environment',
                            'Value' => AwsHelper::getEnvironment($container)
                        ],
                        [
                            'Name'  => 'Container',
                            'Value' => $container   
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}

protected function _getInstanceCount($container){
    $beanstalk = AWS::get('ElasticBeanstalk');
    $resources = $beanstalk->describeEnvironmentResources([
        'EnvironmentName' => AwsHelper::getEnvironment($container)
    ])->get('EnvironmentResources');

    return count($resources['Instances']);
}
```

AwsHelper is a custom class that is only used here to retrieve the environment of a container. AWS is the official AWS SDK for PHP: http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/

I used these docs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.CloudWatch.CloudWatchClient.html#_putMetricData

Answer (score 9):

In order to do this Enable Group Metrics Collection on the Auto Scaling Group.
To do this go to EC2 Dashboard -> Auto Scaling Groups. Find the group you want to collect metrics on and then use the Enable Group Metrics Collection under the monitoring tab.
Once that was completed, you can see the group in CloudWatch under the Scaling Group bucket.

Hope this helps.

Comment: After performing this answer, new metrics like "GroupTotalInstances" become available under ElasticBeanstalk -> Monitoring (click add to add a graph).

Answer (score 0):

Have a read of this post

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-to-add-cloudwatch-monitors-to-auto-scale-your-amazon-web-service/#.

Basically you set up the cloudwatch alerts or graphs on your autoscaling group not your ec2 instances. Set it up for cpu average and scale based on the alarms.

Comment: That post basically explains how to set up auto scaling, which we already have up and running. I'm searching for methods to fine tune the values that are used for up and downscaling, one of the methods would be looking at an running instances history in CloudWatch but I can't seem to find the graphs for that (main part of my question).

Answer (score 0):

To do a similar thing with *default* EC2/ASG configuration, use the `HealthyHostCount` metric for the load balancer with which your elastic beanstalk environment is associated.

Assuming all your hosts are healthy, then it'll effectively be the same as the auto scaling group's instance count.

In "CloudWatch > Metrics", search for "healthyhostcount" and you'll be presented with a list of load balancers. Select the one for the EB environment you want to monitor.